# Issue trying to add Python27 to path through command-line/gitbash

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to add python 2.7 to my currently set path in the command line. I can not get it to add.

My current path looks like this

`Environment variable python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\;C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\jandali\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Python27\Lib" not defined`

at then end it said that 
Environment varialbe python is not defined.

I tried the following commands

`set "%path%;C:\Python27"`

and

`set "%path%;C:\Python27\Lib"`

not sure why it is saying that it is not defined when it is at the end of the paths...

when I run `python` or `python27`, it says that `command was not recognized`

not sure how to fix this.

Comment: If it is bash not cmd, then try using `PATH="$PATH:C:\Python27\"`. You can use `echo $PATH` to see if it was added.

Comment: Are you running your command line as administrator? If not, try to run a windows command line as administrator (right click on command prompt and select Run as Administrator). Then run your command.

Comment: when i run the PATH=... It shows a caret on the side like i have entered the python shell. do I need to do add anything to the command... @solarc

Comment: Ah wait, bash in windows uses a different path format. Try `PATH="$PATH:/c/Python27/"`. It should return you to the regular prompt.

Answer (score 0):

On standard Windows command line, the error you have is because

```
set "%path%;C:\Python27"
```

expands as

```
set superlongcurrentuser+systempath;C:\python27
```

and the variable name just created isn't a valid name. You want:

```
set path="%path%;C:\Python27"
```

(in windows, paths are separated by semicolons, not colons like on unix/linux)